# How could you use mirror in unity to network across multiple networks rather than only LAN (Port Forwarding?)

Tags: unity, networking, multiplayer

I've been working on a game for my friends and I to play during quarantine but I can't figure out or find any information on networking using mirror. Everything I see gives vague answers to even vaguer questions that assume you have prior knowledge of networking. Could anyone give me any sort of direction on how to port forward using mirror or if there's a better solution?

Comment: Port forwarding is generally configured on your router, not in the game. Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @DMGregory I have a main menu that allows people to join through an IP but right now it only works as a LAN server. I'm trying to have people be able to join through several wifi connections so I can play with friends online.

Comment: Sounds like port forwarding on your router is what you need then. Have you had any specific difficulty making that work, following the manufacturer's directions for your particular router model?

Comment: Hi my issue was really just that I didn't fully understand what port forwarding even was. I was under the impression that it was done through scripting rather than online. I figured everything out, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: If you solved your problem, want to write up your solution as an Answer below? It might help future devs who are wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video solved my issue, give it a watch if you had the same issue!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfSLxs40sIw

The main points of the video to my understanding are the following:

Port forwarding is a way to connect several lan networks together.
To port forward, start by opening command prompts and entering ipconfig. Then, copy your default gateway ip into whatever browser you use. From there, you can find the default password for your router at https://www.routerpasswords.com/ . From there, it differs depending on what brand of router you own but you need to look for something that says port forwarding. The default port for mirror is 7777 so enter that where it asks for the port and pick your computer where it asks for a device. Now, wherever you type an ip to connect using unity just have your friends enter your public ip. You can find it by typing "What is my IP address" in your browser.